# Invalid syntax calling function with parameter constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

**Some context**

I am currently trying, in .NET framework 4.7.2, to implement a generic way to call my data server. I have some difficulties to use a generic approach using constraints and an interface

I think it's worth telling that wrong or bad using of interface in my code is possible because it is the first time I try to use it, feel free to suggest any improvement that I could make

Here is the interface that I created :

```cs
public interface IServerConfigDataBase<TProxy, TProxyInput, TProxyOutput> where TProxy : InheritedProxyClass<TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>
                                                                          where TProxyInput : class
                                                                          where TProxyOutput : StandardizedOutput
{
    TProxy Proxy { get; set; }  // Generic class of the proxy I'll use

    string FunctionName { get; set; }  // Used for information in case of error

    void RequestErrorHandle(Exception e);  // Function to call in case of error during the request
}
```

And here is a class using the interface that I created :

```cs
public class ServerFunctionName : IServerConfigDataBase<ProxyName, ProxyInputName, ProxyOutputName>
{
    public ProxyName Proxy { get; set; }
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    public ServerFunctionName(InputDataClass inputValues, string functionName)
    {
        Proxy        = ProxyName.Create();
        Proxy.Input  = new InputContainer {InputData = inputValues};
        FunctionName = functionName;
    }

    public void RequestErrorHandle(Exception e)
    {
        // Display an error message to the user
        ServerRequestUtility.HandleServerException(Proxy.Output.NormalizedData, e, FunctionName);
    }
}
```

I made a function to use the `ServerFunctionName` class to request the server :

```cs
public static StandardizedOutput RequestServer<TServerBase, TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>(TServerBase server) where TServerBase : IServerConfigDataBase<InheritedProxyClass<TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>, TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>
                                                                                             where TProxyInput : class
                                                                                             where TProxyOutput : StandardizedOutput
{
    try
    {
        server.Proxy.Execute();  // Calling the server and actualize the content of server.Proxy.Output
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        server.RequestErrorHandle(e);
    }

    return server.Proxy.Output;
}
```

**The problem**

Now what I struggle with is calling this last function. When I try to do this :

```cs
ServerServiceRequest.RequestServer<ServerFunctionName, ProxyInputName, ProxyOutputName>(
    new ServerFunctionName(
        new InputContainer { Property = "" },
        "nameOfFunction"));
```

I get the error [CS0311](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0311?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0311)) with the following message :

> The type 'ServerFunctionName' cannot be used as type parameter 'IServerConfigDataBase' in the generic type or method 'ServerServiceRequest.RequestServer<ServerFunctionName, ProxyInputName, ProxyOutputName>(TServerBase)'.
>
> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ServerFunctionName' to 'IServerConfigDataBase<InheritedProxyClass<ProxyInputName, ProxyOutputName>, ProxyInputName, ProxyOutputName>'.

I understood that I try to use the class `ServerFunctionName` as the interface `IServerConfigDataBase` and that it won't work, but I can't figure out what I did wrong and how to solve it.

Many thanks

Comment: You are not showing the declarations of _all_ types mentioned, such as `ServerFunctionName`.

Comment: `ServerFunctionName` is declared in [the second code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585094/invalid-syntax-calling-function-with-parameter-constraints?noredirect=1#comment129981890_73585094:~:text=And%20here%20is,NormalizedData%2C%20e%2C%20FunctionName), I don't see which other type I didn't show, could you tell which ones they are?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple Interface for the Proxy class? and inject the real proxy in the ServerFunctionName?

Comment: @EduBic the Proxy class is generated by the company framework, I can modify it but it is not allowed by the company developing politics. Because of that, I cannot use the interface for the proxy class unfortunately. Because of this reason, I too have to use the `ProxyName` class instead of directly interacting with the proxy

Comment: `InheritedProxyClass<TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>` is the interface that you need in the `ServerFunctionName` instead of the class `ProxyName`.

Comment: @EduBic that looks interesting, working on it

Comment: @EduBic sorry, forgot to update, with what you said I used the `InheritedProxyClass<TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>` and removed the constraint on the interface. This way, I managed to use the interface just as a reminder of what is needed in my `ServerFunctionName` (while still being able to use `InheritedProxyClass` content), and it also allowed me to lighten constraints on the `RequestServer` function. Thanks for your suggestion, if you want to make an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InheritedProxyClass<TProxyInput, TProxyOutput>` is the interface that you need in the `ServerFunctionName` instead of the class `ProxyName`.

I don't think use of Generic in this context is useful.